# How to place a \mathcal{D} below the text "err"

Tags: math-mode

[image]

If `err` is  a operator, I know how to do it, but `err`is a text, I don't know how to do it.

Comment: What is the question? Does `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\err}{err}
\begin{document}
  \[\err_{\mathcal{D}}(f)\]
\end{document}
` serve you?

Comment: yes， this is a way，

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First a glimpse from `amsmath` manual (page 17):

[image]

What you need is

```
\DeclareMathOperator*{\err}{err}
```

To have `\mathscr`, load `mathrsfs` too.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathrsfs}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\err}{err}
\begin{document}
  \[\err_{\mathscr{D}}(f)\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

As noted by  barbara beeton in her comments, the font of `err` is fraktur. To reproduce the same, load `amsfonts` package additionally and then define

```
\DeclareMathOperator*{\err}{\mathfrak{err}}
```

[image]

Comment: in the example shown in the question, the "err" is set in a fraktur font.  i don't know whether that is important here (sometimes it is), but if so, the "text" of the operator name could be set as `{$\mathfrak{err}$}`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Thanks. Obviously you have better eyes than me. I have added a note accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Harish Kumar's comment you can also use `\underset` from the `amsmath` package to really place it below the err operator. So in addition to declaring the err operator you can set it then like this:

```
\[
  \underset{\mathcal{D}}{\err}
\]
```