# How can I define a new operator, which works the same as sum, prod in both inline and display math mode?

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

I want to define a new operator say `\Delta` . Which works as the same as `\sum` or `\prod` in both in line and display math mode. Say, the subscribes is to the right of the operator in the in line mode, and under the operator in the display mode. How can we do this?

Comment: Related: [How to place a \mathcal{D} below the text "err"](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/276519)

Comment: Should the `\Delta` symbol be larger in displaystyle mode than in textstyle, scriptstyle, and scriptscriptstyle math mode? Please advise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want it to be literally the size of `\sum`, then this twist will scale the `\Delta` to match the vertical footprint of `\sum`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,scalerel}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\Del}{\scalerel*{\Delta}{\sum}}
\begin{document}
  $\Del_{i=0}^n x_i=0$
  \[\Del_{i=0}^n x_i=0\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you and Harishu Kumar. These are exactly what I want.

Answer (score 9):

You can do it with `\DeclareMathOperator*` provided by `amsmath`. Refer to `amsmath` manual, page 17 for more details.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\Del}{\Delta}
\begin{document}
  $\Del_x^y=0$
  \[\Del_x^y=0\]
\end{document}
```

[image]