# Best way to refactor of more complicated TeX

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I need do refactoring ugly equations.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$
  \sum_{l=1}^{n}
  \frac{x_{k}}{\left(\overset{n}{\underset{l=1}{\sum}}\vert
      x_{l}\vert^{p}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}}\
  \frac{y_{k}}{\left(\overset{n}{\underset{l=1}{\sum}}\vert
      y_{l}\vert^{q}\right)^{\frac{1}{q}}} \text{ } \leq
  \overset{n}{\underset{l=1}{\sum}} \frac{x_{i}^{p}}{p
      \sum_{j=1}^n (x_{i}^{p})^{\frac{1}{p} p}} + \frac{y_{i}}{(q
      \sum_{j=1}^n y_{i}^{q})^{\frac{1}{q}q}}= \frac{1}{p} +
    \frac{1}{q} = 1
$
\end{document}
```

What is your experience to create more flexibility TeX?

I consider using `command` to underscore `\sum`. What is your opinion about this solution?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What you would like to have is not very clear. Could you explain more? What do call ‘flexibility’?

Comment: I learn Latex, and I need more information how I should write code like this. I think prepare special commands for adjusting \sum.  It is right idea?

Comment: Is your equation inline or displayed on a line of its own?

Comment: For own  script. It's similar proof of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2148138/proving-holders-inequality-for-sums

Comment: please provide a test file, your output looks odd, why is the outer sum in inline mode and the inner sum in display?

Comment: It's issue of this solution, When I tried preparing the standard of inner sum, I decided wrote, because the code of LateX was too long.

Comment: it is impossible to understand your question in its current form, the fragment you have provided can not be run on its own, it also appears to be in error missing `\right` ? but hard to tell as it can not be run, but also what is your actual question

Comment: First things first please understand in-line and display math mode and the differences between them: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301672/making-the-product-operator-pi-caps-with-the-extremes-above-and-below-the-symb/301677#301677

Comment: I edited your question so the code can be run but note that it generates an error. If you get _any_ error do not even look at the output PDF, fix or ask a question about the error, copying the error message from the log file.  TeX makes no attempt to make sensible typeset output after an error.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I fixed problem with ```\left```, many thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: `\overset{n}{\underset{l=1}{\sum}`: How about `\sum\limits_{l=1}^n`?

Comment: @HenriMenke I suggested result of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2148138/proving-holders-inequality-for-sums.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The posted code is missing a `\right` so that it generates an error. Once that is fixed, the main stylistic error in the coding is using `\underset` and `\overset` rather than limits on the sum, and using textstyle rather than displaystyle for the expression.

I would use something more like the following although it is rather wide so perhaps use an amsmath multi-line display environment such as `align` rather than `\[ \]`

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
  \sum_{l=1}^{n}
  \frac{x_{k}}{\left(\sum_{l=1}^{n}\lvert x_{l}\rvert^{p}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}}
  \frac{y_{k}}{\left(\sum_{l=1}^{n}\lvert y_{l}\rvert^{q}\right)^{\frac{1}{q}}}
   \leq
  \left(\sum_{l=1}^{n} \frac{x_{i}^{p}}{p \sum_{j=1}^n (x_{i}^{p})^{\frac{1}{p} p}} +
                     \frac{y_{i}}{(q \sum_{j=1}^n y_{i}^{q})^{\frac{1}{q}q}}\right)
    = \frac{1}{p} +\frac{1}{q}
     = 1
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I also suggest that you define macros for often used expressions. Here is an adaptation of David Carlisle's answer using macros:

[image]

Below, I have defined two macros for the two expressions that are repeated. The only difference between them is one uses `x/p` and the other uses `y/q`. Of course, you should pick more meaningful names for the two macros.

Besides ensuring consistency, this makes the code a bit easier to read.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand*{\AbsSumFraction}[2]{%
    % #1 = variable: x,y
    % #2 = exponent p, q
    \frac{#1_{k}}{\left(\sum_{l=1}^{n}\lvert #1_{l}\rvert^{#2}\right)^{\frac{1}{#2}}}%
}
\newcommand*{\SumFraction}[2]{%
    % #1 = variable: x,y
    % #2 = exponent p, q
    \frac{x_{i}^{p}}{p \sum_{j=1}^n (x_{i}^{p})^{\frac{1}{p} p}}
}

\begin{document}
\[
    \sum_{l=1}^{n} \AbsSumFraction{x}{p} \AbsSumFraction{y}{q}
    \le \left( \sum_{l=1}^{n}  \SumFraction{x}{p} + \SumFraction{y}{q} \right)
    = \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q}
    = 1
\]
\end{document}
```